# How to save a class that does not match a data attribute value to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some basic html:

```
<button data-date="hello"></button>
<path class="hello bye">
```

JS

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var pathClass = $("path").attr("class");
  var curClass = $(this).attr("data-date");
   if($(this).hasClass(curClass)) {
     <-- save the other class `BYE` in a variable -->
   }
});
```

I am trying to save in a variable the class which doesn't match the data-date attribute.

Comment: Your "html" does not have any `btn` class. Please post relevant html also.

Comment: @palaѕн just updated

Comment: @palaѕн that's the only html of interest

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the class that you found from existing classes like:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var pathClass = $("path").attr("class");
  var curClass = $(this).attr("data-date");
  if ($("path").hasClass(curClass)) {

    // split the pathClass by space and store them into a array
    var arr = pathClass.split(' ');

    // Here we get all the classes except the current class
    // using array filter method
    // this return a new array, which we join and form a comma
    // seperated string (csv)
    var otherClasses = arr.filter(c => c != curClass).join(', ');
    console.log(otherClasses);

    $("path").attr("data-location", otherClasses);
    console.log('data-location: ' + $("path").attr("data-location"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-date="hello">Click Me!</button>
<path class="hello bye ciao hey">
```

**More Info:-**

- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that, because I will remove the class like that

Comment: I was more looking into using `.filter` maybe? but I don't know much about it

Comment: ok thanks! Could you explain a bit more what the code does please? Also for future reference for any users. Thanks

Comment: What if we have `<path class="hello bye ciao hey">`? if we then do `$("path").attr("data-location", otherClasses);` then we will only have the last class saved `hey` while I should be able to save all the other classes

Comment: What is `data-location` & `remainClass` here?

Comment: remainClass is your otherClssses, the data-location is just an attribute where I am storing the other classes but it looks like only saving the last one

Comment: I am still having only the class .fadeOut in console when using this https://pastebin.com/dbTbVBAb

Comment: Not getting what is the issue here. can you create a demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and explain what is not working and how to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** jQuery here...

Also if you are using data-attributes, try to use **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** jQuery to get data attributes...

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var pathClass = $("path").attr("class");
  var curClass = $(this).data("date");
  var remainClass = pathClass.replace(curClass, "").trim();
  console.log(remainClass);
  $("p b").text(remainClass)
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-date="hello">Click</button>
<path class="hello bye ciao hey">
<p>Remaining Classes: <b></b></p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that, because I will remove the class like that, I was more looking into using `.filter` maybe? but I don't know much about it

Comment: @downFast what do you mean by  `because I will remove the class like that`...?

Comment: I need to keep the class `curClass` and if I use `replace` I am basically giving it a `null`, like removing it.

Comment: @downFast this will not replace the `curClass` class...it will just store the value in a variable...check updated answer...!

Comment: I see, what if we have `<path class="hello bye ciao hey">`? if we then do `$("path").attr("data-location", remainClass);` then we will only have the last class saved `hey` while I should be able to save all the other classes

Comment: @downFast what is `data-location` here...?

Comment: @downFast BTW I updated my answer with your new example and its working fine...Have a look...

Comment: data-location is just an attribute where I am saving the other classes

Comment: I am still having only the class .fadeOut in console when using this https://pastebin.com/dbTbVBAb

Comment: @downFast try to understand...without your complete code not possible to resolve your issue...how can you think that with the website link we will be able to debug the code...so better to make a working example [**here**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/)...